# Please explain object versioning in the nodejs module system

Tags: javascript, architecture, node.js, encapsulation

This question is about the persistance of variables across different modules in nodejs when they don't directly "require" each other, but do "require" a common ancestor.

It is also the generalised version of [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937305/if-a-nodejs-module-exports-an-object-to-two-other-modules-do-changes-made-to-th). Whilst I received an answer there that helped me solve my specific case, I'm still unclear as to the answer to the architectural problem I posed. I hoped that the general problem was a good fit for a programmers.stackexchange question.

Assume we have a nodejs program structured like so:

- Module Alpha - exports variable a.
- Module Beta - requires module Alpha, reads variable a -> prints it to console periodically
- Module Gamma - requires module Alpha, periodically writes to variable a

Is the instance of module Alpha, and thus variable a, common across all three modules. e.g. can module Gamma make changes to variable a that are successfully printed to the console by module Beta.

If this is true, why is this true **even though there is no direct "requires" relationship between modules Gamma and Beta?**

If this is not true, **can you explain the best way to share a variable than needs to be modified at runtime between multiple node modules?**

Can you explain the underlaying data model which is causing this behaviour in nodejs modules?

Comment: I'm not a node expert but it looks like you want to know about [the singleton pattern in NodeJS](http://simplapi.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/node-js-singleton-structure/).

Comment: Thanks! That is an implementation of what I'm after, but what I really want is a canonical answer that explains why that works, and how best to use it to communicate between different node modules. The reason I want it is because even after all my googling, doc reading and api studying, I couldn't find the information I needed to come to that answer myself. This is pretty fundamental knowledge for building non-trivial node applications. and there seems to me to be a serious lack of documentation floating around on how to do it properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the critical piece you're missing is that the result of `require("foo")` is *always the same object*. Consider this REPL example:

```
> var myHttpModule = require("http")
{ ... }
> myHttpModule.someNewProperty = "someValue"
'someValue'
> require("http").someNewProperty
'someValue'
```

The second call to `require("http")` did not re-create the `http` module -- it summoned up the *only `http` module that exists* in Node's current execution environment, which had been altered on the previous line.

So, in your example, there's only one Alpha module. When Beta and Gamma call `require("alpha")`, they're each getting the *same* reference to the one-and-only Alpha module singleton object.

(Or, to be *perfectly* precise, they're getting the same reference to the `exports` value of the Alpha module. `require` *creates* a `Module` object, but *returns* only the `exports` property of that module. If you don't fully understand the distinction right now, it's not a big deal.)

**Behind the scenes: what's really going on with `require` caching?**

The first time you use `require` to include a module, Node actually runs the code in that module. The resulting module is stored in [`require.cache`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_cache). Subsequent attempts to load the module with `require` first check for an already-loaded module object in `require.cache`. (**Note:** environment-native built-in Node modules like `http` are exceptions in that they *don't* use `require.cache` -- you'll need to test out my code below with a custom module.)

`require.cache` is an object whose keys are module file path, with associated values that are module objects. For example, assume some module named "`foo`" in `C:\node_modules\foo.js`:

```
> require.cache                             // empty cache
{ } 
> require("foo")                            // require foo
{ bar: 'baz' }
> require.cache                             // cache now populated
{ 'C:\\node_modules\\foo.js':
   { id: 'C: \\node_modules\\foo.js',
     exports: { bar: 'baz' },
     parent: { ... },
     filename: 'C:\\node_modules\\foo.js',
     ...
     paths:
      [ ... ] } }
```

The current value of the `foo` module is in `require.cache["C:\node_modules\foo.js"].exports`. We can use [`require.resolve`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_resolve) to get the file path of the module from the name, so we can express it also as `require.cache[require.resolve("foo")].exports`.

If we call `require("foo")` a second time, Node sees that `require.cache[require.resolve("foo")]` is defined, and so it returns the value of `require.cache[require.resolve("foo")].exports` instead of re-running the module creation code. This `exports` property of the `foo` module in `require.cache` is the single instance of the `foo` module export value, returned with every subsequent call to `require("foo")`.

One interesting implication here is that you can `delete require.cache[require.resolve("foo")]` to force a reload of the `foo` module with the next call to `require("foo")`, because the object describing the module is removed from the `require.cache` object.

**So what does this mean for me?**

Without `require`, you could still share values between modules using global variables. For example, your Alpha/Beta/Gamma case would work just as well with just Beta and Gamma setting and reading the global value `global.a`. Instead, with Node's `require` system, you're actually setting and reading `global.require.cache[require.resolve("alpha")].exports.a`, which Node lets you read neatly as just `require("alpha").a`.

In fact, if you just want to share a value and don't need to import your shared data as a module, you could also use a namespacing object, i.e., have Beta and Gamma set and read properties of the object `global.alpha`. The major advantage to using `require` is that you don't need to set up `require("alpha")` external to the other scripts, whereas you would need to define `global.alpha = {}` before `require`ing Beta and Gamma. (Alternatively, you could conditionally define `global.alpha` in each module based on a `typeof global.alpha == 'undefined'` check instead, to see if it's the first module to use it.)

Answer (score 3):

Data sharing between modules depends on how and what modules exports. It's important to keep in mind that require() caches and returns the `exports` variable. For instance:

```
// alpha.js 
module.exports.a = 5; // returns 'exports' which is an empty object
                      // with "a" as a property. node caches this object

// gamma.js
var alpha = require("alpha");
alpha.a = 666;  // alpha is a reference to the exports object

// beta.js
var alpha = require("alpha");
console.log(alpha.a); // prints 666
```

Updating it (alpha.a = 666) should work. This means that beta.js should indeed get the latest value each time.

But if you do:

```
// alpha.js
module.exports = 5; // returns it as an integer which is cached by node.

// gamma.js
var alpha = require("alpha");
alpha = 666; // overwrites the local copy, but nothing else happens

// beta.js
var alpha = require("alpha");
console.log(alpha); // still prints 5
```

By the way, doing:

```
// alpha.js
exports = 5;
```

fails because that code is (conceptually) like this:

```
// alpha.js
module.exports = {};
var exports = module.exports;
exports = 5;
return module.exports; // returns {}, not 5
```